# Using Node.js readline in transform streams

Tags: node.js, stream, readline

We have a huge text file which we want to manipulate using stream line by line.

Is there a way to use Node.js [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) module in a [transform](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform) stream?  For instance to make the whole text to use capital letter (processing it line by line)?

Answer (score 1):

[`event-stream`](https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream) might be a better fit. It can split the input on lines and transform those lines in various ways (+ more).

For instance, to uppercase everything read from stdin:

```
const es = require('event-stream');

process.stdin
  .pipe(es.split())                              // split lines
  .pipe(es.mapSync(data => data.toUpperCase()))  // uppercase the line
  .pipe(es.join('\n'))                           // add a newline again
  .pipe(process.stdout);                         // write to stdout
```

Comment: BEWARE! This package has been archived (possibly not maintained any more) and has a serious security risk as per https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream/issues/115